Troubleshooting Column Creation in PgAdmin
I need to create a table in PgAdmin with a large number of columns (more than 900). To streamline the process, I first created an empty table named 'RA2019' and attempted to generate all the columns automatically before importing data from a CSV file. However, I encountered an issue during the column creation process. I used the following code:
COPY schema_name."table_name" ("Column_1, Column_2, … Column_n");

But this resulted in an error message:

ERROR: syntax error at or near ";".

Thank you for your assistance.
Filipe
I removed the ';', yet the problem persists

Where’s your from/to?

Don't use double quotes " around your column names. In this example you even used them in the wrong place, you create just one column with a pretty strange name: Column_1, Column_2, … Column_n. Just never use upper case in your object names, just don't do it. It will always result in bugs.

By the way, COPY doesn't create a column, that's for reading or writing external data.
